# threejs how to get geometry of loaded models using OBJMTLloder on callback

Tags: three.js

How to get the geometry of loaded models using OBJMTLloder on callback, i can't get the geometry of the loaded object, if i get it with the object traverse  can get the only one portion of the object, i want to get the geometry of the object dynamically to scale the object into center of the scene

```
object.traverse( function ( child ) {
      if (child instanceof THREE.Mesh) {

          var  geometry = child.geometry;
          material = child.material;

          child.material.needsUpdate = true;
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to scale the object you dont need to use the `traverse()` method. You can do:

```
object.scale.x = x_scale;
object.scale.y = y_scale;
object.scale.z = z_scale;
```

You can also use the `BoundingBoxHelper()` method to find the approximate size of the object.